# How to implement dynamic reflections in A-Frame

Tags: aframe

I have an A-Frame scene consisting of a horizontal plane, some lights and a vertical plane on which a video is playing. I am trying to achieve reflections on the horizontal plane such that the vertical plane above it is reflected. I intend to set reduced opacity on the reflective surface. How can one do this in A-Frame?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I write a `mirror` component, here is my code:

```
<script>
AFRAME.registerComponent('mirror', {
schema:{
    renderothermirror:{default:true},
},
init: function () {
    var scene = this.el.sceneEl;
    scene.addEventListener('render-target-loaded',this.OnRenderLoaded.bind(this));
},
OnRenderLoaded: function()
{
    var mirrorObj = this.el.getOrCreateObject3D('mesh',THREE.Mesh);
    var cameraEl = document.querySelector('a-entity[camera]')
    if(!cameraEl)
    {
        cameraEl = document.querySelector('a-camera');
    }
    var camera = cameraEl.components.camera.camera;
    var scene = this.el.sceneEl;
    this.renderer = scene.renderer;
    this.mirror = new THREE.Mirror( this.renderer, camera, { clipBias: 0.003, textureWidth: window.innerWidth, textureHeight: window.innerHeight, color: 0x777777 } );
    mirrorObj.material =this.mirror.material;
    mirrorObj.add(this.mirror);
},
tick: function () {
    if(!this.data.renderothermirror)
        {
            this.mirror.render();
        }
    else
        {
            var mirrors = [];
            var mirrorEls = document.querySelectorAll("a-entity[mirror]");
            for(var i=0;i<mirrorEls.length;i++)
            {
                if(mirrorEls[i]!=this.el)
                {
                    mirrors.push(mirrorEls[i].components.mirror.mirror);
                }   
            }
            if(mirrors.length === 0)
            {
                this.mirror.render();
            }
            for(var i = 0; i<mirrors.length;i++)
            {
                this.mirror.renderWithMirror(mirrors[i]);
            }
        }
}
});
</script>
```

You also need to use Mirror.js, you can find it here:[Mirror.js](https://threejs.org/examples/js/Mirror.js)

Just attach the `mirror` component to your planes. e.g. `<a-plane mirror>`.

Comment: After discussion with Craig.Li I've changed the tick function slightly to handle the case of `renderothermirror: true` and only having one mirror:

`var mirrorEls = document.querySelectorAll("a-entity[mirror]");`
`if(!this.data.renderothermirror || mirrorEls.length === 1)`

Comment: The link to Mirror.js is dead. And a simple complete example would be grate.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a component for these kinds of live dynamic reflections. It has a special "floor" mode. Available here:

https://github.com/kylebakerio/a-dynamic-reflection

[image]